# Dynamically creating a type with a field the same type as its owner at run time

Tags: c#, reflection

So I am currently writing code that generates objects at run time. Much like in [This Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862226/dynamically-create-a-class-in-c-sharp).

However I'm having trouble finding any information regarding dynamically creating a type with that same type embedded in it. something like:

```
public class Foo
{
    private Foo _Parent

    public Foo()
    {}

    public Foo Parent
    {
        get { return _Parent; }
        set { _Parent = value; }
    }
}
```

Is there any way to do this in c# using reflection or emit?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Today I learned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2230440/im-attempting-to-write-a-net-compiler-using-system-reflection-emit-how-do-i-do) you can cast a `TypeBuilder` to a `Type` to get a handle on the type it's going to build:

```
TypeBuilder tb = // get from a ModuleBuilder or wherever
Type typeImAboutToBuild = (Type)tb;

FieldBuilder fb = tb.DefineField(
    "_Parent", typeImAboutToBuild, FieldAttributes.Private)
```

Edit: `TypeBuilder` actually *inherits* from `Type`, rather than this being an `explicit` or `implicit` conversion operation; you don't even need the cast:

```
TypeBuilder tb = //whatever
FieldBuilder fb = tb.DefineField("_Parent", tb, FieldAttributes.Private)
```